# Monitoring Network Useage

Tags: unix, bandwidth, monitoring

I have a server (running Ubuntu, but I can put a BSD/Solaris or other distro on if that helps) running beween my LAN and my sattelite modem (basically acting as a router).  I would like to track inbound/outbound Internet useage in both time and bytes on a per-mac-address basis.  How would I go about doing this?  What utilities do I need?

Comment: i suggest you stick to per-ip monitoring and trace mac-ip associations via arpwatch [ you'll also find it in defualt ubuntu / debian repository ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at:

- [bandwidthd](http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/)
- [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/)

you'll find them in standard debian / ubuntu repository and both will provide you network usage stats based on ip in given subnet [ lan ] in last 24h / week / month.

bandwidthd will give you very basic breakdown of stats based on different protocols; ntop can provide you more detailed info.

both can be generate quite heavy load on the server if you analyze streams of tens of megabits, but i think you dont have to worry since probably you handle few mbits.

Comment: I had looked at bandwidthd before. Can it log by MAC or just by IP? People on my network have dynamic IPs, and I may not always know in advance what their MACs will be before they use (I can always collect later to correlate person to MAC)

Comment: Ooh, ntop seem to definitely have MAC logging

Answer (score 0):

apt-get netspeed -y in fedora and centos gnmoe-applets-netspeed.*.rpm http://projects.gnome.org/netspeed// even you use ntop